# Does Killing A Bash Process Affect Children Processes

Tags: bash, rsync, tar, bash-scripting

### The Scenario

I'm automating backups via a `bash` script. The script is executed via `cron`. The script archives directories recursively using `tar`, and then `rsync`'s them to the remote host. Here is a sample:

```
...
for PATH in $DIRS
do
    ...
    tar -cpvzf $FFILE $PATH --exclude-from /tmp/excludes
    ...
    rsync -az --partial --rsync-path="sudo rsync" $FFILE mybackupserver:$REMOTEFILES
    ...
done
...
```

Each time `tar` or `rsync` is invoked, a new process (and therefore PID) is spawned for each one, obviously.

### My Question

If I kill the process that started the *script*, will the child `tar` and `rsync` processes also be killed off immediately? Or will they run until completion, and no further ones will be spawned thereafter?

I'm reluctant to interrupt the `tar` or `rsync` processes mid-stream.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to google for "nohup" - in short, what happens to the child process depends on how signal handling was set up when it was started (or changed at a later PIT)

Answer (score 1):

They will become orphan processes, becoming children of the script's parent. Usually they will become descendants of init.

Comment: OK, so they *do* get interrupted?